# understanding TYPE in lsof output

Tags: lsof

I opened a file through python. So, i did a lsof on the python process. output of lsof has the following line

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
python  15855 inaflash    3w   REG   0,25        0 4150810088 /home/inaflash/he.txt
```

Thing is, it has `3w`. which means that the file is open for writing. But, i actually opened the file as follows

`a = open('he.txt','r')`

I read that, `w` means file is open for write. Can anyone help me understand why its `w` instead of `r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same code in Python 3 and my file is opened in read mode.

[image]

[image]

Are you sure your file is the same opened with python and same python process ?
Maybe you forgot to close the file somewhere in your code after opened it in write mode.

Edit: Also tried in Python 2, same result (read mode)

Comment: Thanks, Actually.. i first opened the file in write mode. Then closed it and then opened the same file in read mode. Then this happened